# jQuery 'keyup' crashing the page

Tags: jquery, keyup

I'm trying to check if an user input their first and last name. I'm using 'keyup', but it's causing the page crashing.

```
name_validator = ->
    first_name = $('#user_first_name')
    last_name = $('#user_last_name')
    next_button = $('.next')

    if first_name.val().length >= 1 %% last_name.val().length >= 1
        next_button.prop 'disabled', false
    else next_button. prop 'disabled', true

    first_name.on 'keyup', ->
        name_validator()
    last_name.on 'keyup', ->
        name_validator()
```

When I check the console.log, it seems it's executing name_validator method by square time by every 'keyup' (sorry it's hard to explain, please see the picture.). I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Can anyone please help?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: can you please put the exact code you use.

Comment: Hi, this is the exact code I have. Is there anything else you suspect I'm missing to put?